# Wrapping WinApi button function in class

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to create a button class in C++ to wrap the `WinApi`. It is polmorphic with its children being objects like pushbutton or radio button.

The problem I have is that I don't know how to store the button handler for when there is a `BN_CLICKED` event. Should I just store it in the class or will it be reset every time `Draw()` is called. Here is my button and pushbutton code, thank you:

```
#pragma once
#include "pch.h"

namespace CH
{
    class Button
    {
    protected:
        int x, y, w, h;
        std::string text;

        virtual bool Draw(HWND hWnd) = 0;
        virtual bool Draw(HWND hWnd, long styles) = 0;
    public:
        Button(int xPos, int yPos, int width, int height, std::string content)
        {
            x = xPos;
            y = yPos;
            w = width;
            h = height;

            text = content;
        }
        ~Button() = default;

        inline int getX() { return x; }
        inline int gety() { return y; }
        inline int getW() { return w; }
        inline int getH() { return h; }


    };
}





////////
// PushButton.h
////////
#pragma once
#include "Button.h"
namespace CH
{
    class PushButton
    : public Button
{
public:
    PushButton(HWND& hWnd, int xPos, int yPos, int width, int height, std::string content)
        : Button(xPos,yPos,width,height,content)
    {
        std::wstring stemp = std::wstring(text.begin(), text.end());

        handler = CreateWindow(
            L"BUTTON",  // Predefined class; Unicode assumed 
            stemp.c_str(),  // Button text 
            WS_TABSTOP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | BS_DEFPUSHBUTTON,  // Styles 
            x,         // x position 
            y,         // y position 
            w,        // Button width
            h,        // Button height
            hWnd,     // Parent window
            NULL,       // No menu.
            (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLongPtr(hWnd, GWLP_HINSTANCE),
            NULL);      // Pointer not needed.
    }

};


}
```

Comment: There are numerous questions on SO related to wrapping Win32 API controls in classes. As for your specific question, `BN_CLICKED` is sent to the button's *parent* window, so that is where you need to handle it. However, `BN_CLICKED` does carry the button's `HWND`, if you want to reflect the message back to the button class for handling. Also, the return values of your `Draw()` methods are *indeterminate* if `CreateWindow()` fails.

Comment: Which part of the `CreateWindow` function call is the button's `HWND`?

Comment: @ScrumptiousGoat: The return value

Comment: `std::wstring stemp = std::wstring(text.begin(), text.end())` - What you hope to be a *"conversion"* is called *"corruption"* when taken at face value. C++ doesn't attribute any particular character encoding to `char` or `wchar_t`. After having forced the former into the latter, the resulting `stemp` is a wide character string of gibberish. That's usually not desirable.

Comment: Creating the window in the Draw method seems a bit of an odd design. Is Draw only going to be called once per object? If not, you'll end up with lots of overlapping buttons.

Comment: Where should I create the window? The constructor?

Comment: @ScrumptiousGoat Maybe you can dispatch messages in the parent window procedure and map the button related messages to the handle of the button class.

Comment: So should I put the `CreateWindow` under the WM_PAINT event? Or is there a better place?

Comment: @ScrumptiousGoat You may receive `WM_PAINT` continuously but only one `WM_CREATE` message. I've no idea of how do you want your button behave but if it is a fixed part of the whole window, it is suggested to create it under `WM_CREATE` message.

Answer (score 0):

The button `HWND` handle is created by `CreateWindow()` and is valid until the window is closed or destroyed.

It will not be reset by `Draw()` and you can simply store it as a member in the base class (`Button`). Make sure you initialize it with `nullptr` on constructor so it’s invalid until the button is created.

Please note that WinAPI buttons already have their own internal `Draw()` function. If you want to implement your own it gets very complicated very fast. You can start without it to keep it simple.